# What should I use? Cache, Localstorage? with Angular 6

Tags: angular, caching, angular6

In my app, I have a right menu that always need the same 5 queries count, but it is not related to the current page. most of the queries are counts();

My question, is what is the more suitable method for this kind of operations. I don't want to execute the same query over and over, and I could easy execute it once, and then, modify the value on the fly.

For instance, one field is num category configured / num category total

So, each time I configure a category, I could increment the local variable.

Is it a way to do it?

Comment: In general, I would not think about too much performance improvement upfront. I agree with your idea, you could simply hold a local variable in a service and call an increment method whenever you want. Your right component would simply show this service attribute.